# How to translate (I18N) error texts raised by validations in the model (Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running an application on Ruby On Rails (3.1) and need to handle translations into various languages. I got my controller texts properly handled using the I18N feautures, but what about validations in models, especially those like this:

```
validate :valid_quantities?

def valid_quantities?
    if self.quantity*self.unitprice < 1.00
    errors.add("The transaction value", "is < 1.00")
    return false
end
```

How would I code this to provide support for other languages?
In addition, how to I handle the formatting of the numbers? I cannot call the ActionView helpers and user e.g. number_to_currency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I made partial progress, looks like the following works:

Change the code in the model validation to

```
errors.add(" ",I18n.t(:valid_quantities,:amount=>1.00))
```

Enter the translation into de.yml

```
de:
    valid_quantities: "Der Mindestwert einer Order ist %{amount}"
```

But I am still looking for a way to format that number correctly (1.00 for English, 1,00 for German).

Answer (score 11):

I would use this:

```
total_price = self.quantity*self.unitprice
errors.add(:transaction_value, :transaction_undervalued, { value: total_price })
```

IMHO you would better use a simple keyword like `:transaction_undervalued`, that way I18n look in several namespaces according to [rails guides - i18n - error message scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-scopes):

```
activerecord.errors.models.[model_name].attributes.transaction_undervalued
activerecord.errors.models.[model_name]
activerecord.errors.messages
errors.attributes.transaction_undervalued
errors.messages
```

*replace [model_name] with the model is using this validation

For the locales part, this is an example in /config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  errors: &errors
    messages:
      transaction_undervalued: "The transaction value is %{value}. That is < 1.00"
```

Answer (score 3):

For standard validations, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-scopes. For your custom validations, why don't you use I18n.t for that?

```
errors.add(:transaction_value, I18n.t("errors.attributes.transaction_value.below_1"))
```

Comment: Cant seem to get it working, I added it as well as added the translation into de.yml as follows
    errors:
        attributes:
            transaction_value:
                below_1: Der Transaktionswert ist kleiner 1.00
  
but I still get the error message:
Transaction value translation missing: de.errors.attributes.transaction_value.below_1

Answer (score 1):

You need to use method `I18n.l` for localising numbers and dates.

Rails guides has some addition info about the localisation of errors, whereby you should be able to add the translations straight into the translation file: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models